# Generalized Cones

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex and $A$ be a subcomplex of $K$ such that $A$ is contractible. Suppose that for any simplex $\sigma\in K\setminus A$ and any vertex $v\in A$, $\sigma\cup \{v\}$ is a simplex in $K$. Is $K$ contractible? Is $K$ some kind of generalized cone? Any suggestion on reference or answer is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is called a *join*. See [join of topological spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+topological+spaces) and [join of simplicial sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/join+of+simplicial+sets).

Comment: Yes. I didn't recognize that! thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand the definition, it is indeed a join but somewhat trivial one. If $\sigma$ is a simplex in $K \setminus A$, then adding $v$ again gives a simplex in $K \setminus A$. By iterating this, full simplex on $A$ belongs to the construction. Overall the result does not seem to depend on the structure (or contractibility) of $A$ but it only gives a join of the subcomplex on vertices of $K \setminus A$ with the full simplex on $A$. (I.e. an iterated cone.)

Comment: What is an iterated cone pls? I think $K$ may not be contractible if $A$ is not. For example $K$ is the surface of  square bipyramid and consider $A$ to be square; this is a suspension of a square, i.e. $\simeq S^2$, also a join of $S^0$ and $S^1$.

Comment: I think that this example does not satisfy your definition. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be the vertices of the square (with $a$ and $c$ oppposite) and $e$, $f$ be the two remaining vertices. Then $ae$ is a simplex in $K \setminus A$ and $c$ belongs to $A$. Thus, according to your condition, $ace$ should belong to $K$ as well but it does not. You probably indeed mean join of two complexes (in this case the square and two isolated points) but the definition is slightly different. With iterated cone, I simply meant taking a cone several times.

Comment: My bad. In my mind, $K\A$ is the induced subcomplex from $K$  with the vertex set $K^{(0)}\setminus A^{(0)}$. Thanks a lot!